# OpenCV 3.0.0 error with Gstreamer

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I just installed OpenCV 3.0 following this tutorial:
http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/

I didn't encounter any error during the installation process. However, when I tried running the a sample program such as the following,

```
cd cpp/
./cpp-example-facedetect lena.jpg // (../data/lena.jpg) OpenCV 3.0 beta
./cpp-example-houghlines pic1.png // (../data/pic1.jpg) OpenCV 3.0 beta
```

I get the following error:

```
Processing 1 lena.jpg
GStreamer: Error opening bin: Unrecoverable syntax error while parsing pipeline lena.jpg
Capture from AVI didn't work
init done 
opengl support available 
In image read
```

I'm a complete newbie to computer vision and I don't have a clue as to what the problem could be. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: I just encountered this error, which had nothing to do with gstreamer, which was already installed. rather, I have a line that says :if(argc==0){
 cap.open(0);  This is where I thought I was setting my video stream, but argc==0 is a typo, and needs to be argc==1. basically, the error might mean the video stream device was not properly set up, prior to calling it. You could declare a default device, using VideoCapture cap(0); then change it later.

Answer (score 3):

I did the same, following the same tutorial.
Only difference I made is with Gstreamer, doing this:

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0

But another thing that is not clear in your question.
The lena.jpg file is not in the same directory, but the data folder (one higher).
So the command line in the cpp folder should be:

> ./cpp-example-facedetect ../data/lena.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I got the first part of this error:
"GStreamer: Error opening bin: Unrecoverable syntax error while parsing pipeline"
with gstreamer installed already. Turns out it was because I was using a "~" in my file path and I forgot that it would not be expanded. Not the most intuitive error message for it not being able to find the file.